table, stylus and touchscreen not working properly after instalaton of 24.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 gen 2 Tablet.  I previously had 22.04 running and my tablet and touchscreen worked well.  In 24.04 they are not working properly.  I am  using "Ubuntu on xorg" and not Wayland. The stylus on the tablet works only intermittently. Pushing a button on the stylus seems to always be registered.  The location of the stylus works about about 40% of the time and even when I can see that the computer knows where the stylus is, pressing the nib into the screen to push an icon, move a window, draw a line, move a card in game, etc. only registers about half the time.
The touchscreen is basically unusable. I can reliably change the window focus by touching in the window where I want to have focus.  I can sometimes scroll using the touchscreen but not reliably. In xournalpp I can scroll with touch but not pinch to zoom.  I cannot move any window by touching and dragging its title bar. I cannot move cards in a card game.
Using xev I can see that the touchscreen registers every touch that I give but I cannot use it. xev also sees the stylus moving even when I can't use it to draw a line in xournalpp.
